# Open windows file share in Finder on Mac via shell script

Tags: bash, macos

My Windows-using colleague gave me a url that looks like this:
`\\server\share\folder`
I'm able to access it on my Mac, via Finder by translating it to:
`smb://server/share/folder`
Would like to write a little bash script to prepend the smb: and flip the wacky backslashes to forward slashes.
My question is: how to open Finder via shell script? and can I feed Finder a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the Finder via a shell script on a Mac simply do:

```
open DIR
```

... where DIR is the directory you want to open. The Mac OS will open Finder, since that is the correct application for directories. e.g.

```
open .
```

... will open the current directory in a Finder window. You should be able to open an smb:// path with that too. The Mac OS should recognize the smb:// prefix and open the appropriate program. If you pass it an http:// path, it'll open using the default web browser.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by making the following shell script which is called via Automator via a keyboard shortcut when the desired Windows path is selected:

```
OUTPUT=$(echo "$1" | sed 's/\\/\//g')
A="${OUTPUT#*Production}"
foo="smb://path/to/network/directory${A}"
open "$foo"
```

Here's what it looks like in Automator:

[image]